# Delphi - Draw text multiline in the centre of a rect

Tags: delphi, text

In Delphi i wish to draw text inside a TRect. I am hoping for the following functionality:

1. Draw the text centred vertically within the TRect
2. Draw the text centred horizontally within the TRect
3. If there is space for more than 1 line of text (using TRect's height), draw the text multiline
4. If the text does not fit in the TRect (either on a single or mult line) then append ellipsis to the text.

I can see the Windows.DrawText() function *almost* covers this functionality, however when writing text, multiline and vertically centred are mutually exclusive.

I was wondering if this functionality is built into windows (2000+)? If not is there a way to do this without writing my own function?

Comment: Can't you use TLabel? I think it has all the functionality required.

Comment: Yes it probably does, but i do not want to use a label, i have a canvas to draw on.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Sorry, this is a combination of all previous answers and comments. But it seems OP needs more assistance.

```
function DrawTextCentered(Canvas: TCanvas; const R: TRect; S: String): Integer;
var
  DrawRect: TRect;
  DrawFlags: Cardinal;
  DrawParams: TDrawTextParams;
begin
  DrawRect := R;
  DrawFlags := DT_END_ELLIPSIS or DT_NOPREFIX or DT_WORDBREAK or
    DT_EDITCONTROL or DT_CENTER;
  DrawText(Canvas.Handle, PChar(S), -1, DrawRect, DrawFlags or DT_CALCRECT);
  DrawRect.Right := R.Right;
  if DrawRect.Bottom < R.Bottom then
    OffsetRect(DrawRect, 0, (R.Bottom - DrawRect.Bottom) div 2)
  else
    DrawRect.Bottom := R.Bottom;
  ZeroMemory(@DrawParams, SizeOf(DrawParams));
  DrawParams.cbSize := SizeOf(DrawParams);
  DrawTextEx(Canvas.Handle, PChar(S), -1, DrawRect, DrawFlags, @DrawParams);
  Result := DrawParams.uiLengthDrawn;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
const
  S = 'This is a very long text as test case for my paint routine.';
var
  R: TRect;
begin
  SetRect(R, 100, 100, 200, 140);
  Canvas.Rectangle(R);
  InflateRect(R, -1, -1);
  Caption := Format('%d characters drawn', [DrawTextCentered(Canvas, R, S)]);
end;
```

Comment: I cant see the difference between deamon_x's and this version but this works!!!! Thanks :)

Comment: This line is the key: DT_END_ELLIPSIS or DT_NOPREFIX or DT_WORDBREAK or DT_EDITCONTROL or DT_CENTER;

Comment: i know turned out to be something simple, but any other combination of the flags didnt work! Woul split the points if i could :)

Comment: @NGLN I hoped your example would solve my issue, but it doesn't, I try to v-center the text within a specified rectangle but if the text doesn't fit and the ELLIPSIS is drawn, the DrawRect.Bottom reports a value representing 3 lines even though only 2 lines are clearly drawn. Here is a sample image showing the issue http://zoomplayer.com/pix/font_vcenter.jpg (The darker area behind the text is the specified rectangle).

Comment: @bLight I think it is best to ask a new question for your specific problem.

Answer (score 5):

Measure the text first using `DT_CALCRECT`. Pass `DT_WORDBREAK` to specify that word wrapping is enabled. This will allow you to find the required height for your text. Then you can, in your code, calculate the vertical offset that gives you vertically centred text, and draw to that offset.

Comment: I tried this method, but it appears for some reason the DT_WORD_ELLIPSIS is ignored when DT_WORDBREAK is specified. This routine currently does not paint text outside of the rect (and doesnt show the '...')

Comment: Is there a way i can get exactly which text (or length) was drawn?

Comment: @Simon With `DT_WORDBREAK` all the text is drawn. You aren't seeing it presumably due to clipping.

Comment: @David, Simon - you need to specify also the `DT_MODIFYSTRING` flag

Comment: Its very close to what i want, however if i shrink the TRect, the text therefore cannot fit in the TRect and i would expect an ellipsis to be shown. However this is not the case, the last word(s) are simply not drawn. I dont think DT_NOCLIP is what i am after

Comment: I have also looked at the DrawTextParams data structure of DrawTextEx, however the uiLengthDrawn which i beleive should return the number of chars drawn always returns the length of the string?

Comment: @Simon As I said I think all the text is drawn and what you can't see is due to clipping.

Comment: @Simon DrawTextParams.uiLengthDrawn returns the number of characters drawn, including the 3 points due to DT_WORD_ELLIPSIS.

Comment: @Simon - I think you're looking for `DT_CENTER or DT_WORDBREAK or DT_END_ELLIPSIS or DT_MODIFYSTRING` this will wrap your text, center it horizontally and display ellipsis at the end of the text in case the last line cannot be displayed entirely.

Comment: You do not need DT_MODIFYSTRING, that's only needed for text handling after painting. Use DT_EDITCONTROL to display only full visible lines. Without, there are partial lines drawn which may be the reason for not seeing the ellipsis.

Comment: @NGLN - feel free to copy the code I've posted. Better will be to show the example than discuss here.