# Add graphical bar to a StringGrid col

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, custom-draw, stringgrid

Using Delphi 2010 and a TStringGrid component, I currently display five filds from a database query.

Here is a simplied example of what i am doing

//set up the grid

```
procedure TGriddata.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
 grdMain.Rows[0].commatext:='"One","Two","Three","Four","Five"';
 grdMain.ColWidths[0]:= 50;
 grdMain.ColWidths[1]:= 175;
 grdMain.ColWidths[2]:= 175;
 grdMain.ColWidths[3]:= 100;
 grdMain.ColWidths[4]:= 300;
end;
```

//display the data in the grid
//note, I am not showing my creation, execution, or destroy of the query

```
procedure TGriddata.load;
begin
 ... 
 grdMain.Cells[0,row]:= FieldByName('one').AsString;
 grdMain.Cells[1,row]:= FieldByName('two').AsString;
 grdMain.Cells[2,row]:= FieldByName('three').AsString;
 grdMain.Cells[3,row]:= FieldByName('four').AsString;
 //draw progress bar here
 ...
end;
```

One of the columns ("Five") needs to display a navy blue horizontal bar in the col. It should also diplay some text centered in the bar. I have no expereince using the custom drawing. What properties do i set to only custom draw the one column and use the default drawing for the other columns?

Comment: See [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7044125/delphi-draw-own-progress-bar-in-list-view/7048062#comment8445655_7048062) by Ian Boyd!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add the text to the cells like you normally would. But you have to draw those bars in the `OnDrawCell` event. Leave `DefaultDrawing` as is (`True` by default), and erase the already drawn cell text in those columns by filling it in advance:

```
procedure TForm1.grdMainDrawCell(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Integer;
  Rect: TRect; State: TGridDrawState);
var
  Progress: Single;
  R: TRect;
  Txt: String;
begin
  with TStringGrid(Sender) do
    if (ACol = 4) and (ARow >= FixedRows) then
    begin
      Progress := StrToFloatDef(Cells[ACol, ARow], 0) / 100;
      Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
      R := Rect;
      R.Right := R.Left + Trunc((R.Right - R.Left) * Progress);
      Canvas.Brush.Color := clNavy;
      Canvas.Rectangle(R);
      Txt := Cells[ACol, ARow] + '%';
      Canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;
      IntersectClipRect(Canvas.Handle, R.Left, R.Top, R.Right, R.Bottom);
      Canvas.Font.Color := clHighlightText;
      DrawText(Canvas.Handle, PChar(Txt), -1, Rect, DT_SINGLELINE or
        DT_CENTER or DT_VCENTER or DT_END_ELLIPSIS or DT_NOPREFIX);
      SelectClipRgn(Canvas.Handle, 0);
      ExcludeClipRect(Canvas.Handle, R.Left, R.Top, R.Right, R.Bottom);
      Canvas.Font.Color := clWindowText;
      DrawText(Canvas.Handle, PChar(Txt), -1, Rect, DT_SINGLELINE or
        DT_CENTER or DT_VCENTER or DT_END_ELLIPSIS or DT_NOPREFIX);
      SelectClipRgn(Canvas.Handle, 0);
    end;
end;
```

[image: Custom drawn bars in StringGrid]

For more options, you might consider [this `DrawStatus` routine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7048062/757830).

Answer (score 4):

Here you can view a sample ([Draw percentage in a cell in a Grid](http://neftali.clubdelphi.com/?p=152)), to draw a bar in a cell of a TStringGrid.
The explanation is in spanish, but you can download the code, that is very simple.
Also you can use authomatic translation on right of page.

[image]

```
procedure TFormDrawCell.DBGrid1DrawColumnCell(Sender: TObject;
  const Rect: TRect; DataCol: Integer; Column: TColumn;
  State: TGridDrawState);
const
  STR_EMPTY = '';
  CHAR_PERCENT = '%';
  SPACE_TO_CENTER_CELLTEXT = 0;
var
  fValue: Integer;
  ActualPenColor, ActualBrushColor: TColor;
  EmptyDS: Boolean;
  DrawRect: TRect;
  fWidth1, fLeft2: Integer;
  StrValue: string;
begin
  if not (Column.FieldName = 'Precent') then
    Exit;

  if not (cbdraw.Checked) then
    Exit;

  EmptyDS := ((TDBGrid(Sender).DataSource.DataSet.EoF) and
              (TDBGrid(Sender).DataSource.DataSet.Bof));

  if (Column.Field.IsNull) then begin
    fValue := -1;
    StrValue := STR_EMPTY;
  end
  else begin
    fValue := Column.Field.AsInteger;
    StrValue := IntToStr(fValue) + CHAR_PERCENT;
  end;

  DrawRect := Rect;
  InflateRect(DrawRect, -1, -1);

  fWidth1 := (((DrawRect.Right - DrawRect.Left) * fValue) DIV 100);

  ActualPenColor := TDBGrid(Sender).Canvas.Pen.Color;
  ActualBrushColor := TDBGrid(Sender).Canvas.Brush.Color;
  TDBGrid(Sender).Canvas.Pen.Color := clHighlight;
  TDBGrid(Sender).Canvas.Brush.Color := clWhite;
  TDBGrid(Sender).Canvas.Rectangle(DrawRect);

  if (fValue > 0) then begin
    TDBGrid(Sender).Canvas.Pen.Color := clSkyBlue;
    TDBGrid(Sender).Canvas.Brush.Color := clSkyBlue;
    DrawRect.Right := DrawRect.Left + fWidth1;
    InflateRect(DrawRect, -1, -1);
    TDBGrid(Sender).Canvas.Rectangle(DrawRect);
  end;

  if not (EmptyDS) then begin
    DrawRect := Rect;
    InflateRect(DrawRect, -2, -2);
    TDBGrid(Sender).Canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;
    fLeft2 := DrawRect.Left + (DrawRect.Right - DrawRect.Left) shr 1 -
              (TDBGrid(Sender).Canvas.TextWidth(StrValue) shr 1);
    TDBGrid(Sender).Canvas.TextRect(DrawRect, fLeft2,
                                    DrawRect.Top + SPACE_TO_CENTER_CELLTEXT, StrValue);
  end;

  TDBGrid(Sender).Canvas.Pen.Color := ActualPenColor;
  TDBGrid(Sender).Canvas.Brush.Color := ActualBrushColor;
end;
```

Regards.

Comment: Please edit your answer and add the code here, instead of just linking to an off-site location. If the external site is not available for some reason, your answer becomes meaningless. It's also not searchable for future readers of the site. Thanks.

Comment: @KenWhite: I took the liberty to post the relevant part of the code here, and made some slight simplifications to make it more readable.

Comment: @Wouter: Thanks. The poster should  have done it themselves, though, especially after being reminded to do so. It was apparently being watched enough for you to get a thanks from them in half an hour or so, so the request should have been seen. :-)