# Wrap Text for add a strings into a TStringGrid

Tags: delphi

I'm developing a program and one of its feature is a text file downloader. When the user presses the button "Download", the program downloads a text file on a Memo with a defined formatting.

Example 1

> user_A:italy
>
> user_B:usa

Each data is divided by ":" and I want add these datas into a StringGrid. So I thought to break the string each time that ":" char is found. The first line of the example on the memo becomes:

Example 2

> user_A
>
> italy

At this point the program adds the lines into a StringGrid, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqbFb.png) you can see an image as example. I wrote this code:

```
for i:= 0 to 4096 do
 begin
   if (length(Memo1.Lines.Strings[i])>0) then
    begin
      StringGrid1.Cells[1,i+1]:=Memo1.Lines.Strings[i];
    end
   else
    begin
      break;
    end;
 end;
```

My problem is the following: when the text in the memo is `user_A:italy` for example, the result isn't a string with 2 lines [user_A(break line)italy], but it's still `user_A:italy`. I'm using this code:

```
s:=Memo1.Text;
s:=WrapText(s, #13#10,[':'],20);
Memo1.Lines.Add(s);
```

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to put CR/LF into a TStringgrid cell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414870/how-to-put-cr-lf-into-a-tstringgrid-cell)

Comment: that is the `WrapText()` issue

Comment: Why wouldn't you break this into two cells ("user" and "country") instead, which would be much easier?